# Use multiple ID'S in DOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, ids

the main idea is to try to disable multiple checkboxes using **multiple ID'S** for example **using documentGetElementById**

Each id belongs to a checkbox

```
function main(){
var a = document.getElementById("actual").value;
var b = document.getElementById("destination").value;

if (a == "Jamaica" && b == "Paris"){
document.getElementById("A", "B", "C", "D").disabled = true; // occupied seats
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1.) Multiple calls

```
document.getElementById("A").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("B").disabled = true;
// and so on...
```

2.) Loop over the IDs

```
["A", "B", "C", "D"].forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).disabled = true)
```

3.) You find a selector that matches all of them and use `document.querySelectorAll`. IDs have to be unique, so that won't suffice, but let's say all checkboxes on the page need to be disabled:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']").forEach(elem => elem.disabled = true);
```

For this option, you can alternatively use other CSS selectors that would select the desired checkboxes, like a class name.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I did not know that method. Have a nice day :)

Comment: No worries :) Feel free to accept an answer of your liking, so StackOverflow marks this as answered and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` takes only one parameter, therefore, you should do:

```
let ids = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
     document.getElementById(ids[i]).disabled = true; // occupied seat
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I did not know that method. Have a nice day :)